# Creating New Dynamic Fields for a Certificate (Number Generation, Code Referencing, and more)

Tags: plugins, php, custom-field, shortcode, widgets

I'm making a certificate that's supposed to autogenerate and involves the need for multiple dynamic fields. I have everything else finished but I have difficulty trying to create 3 dynamic fields. These are:

- Student's birth year (used as identity verification number and will be used as a dynamic field on their certificate; this prevents fraud).
- The date the course/exam was completed (exam/course completion date
  is the same date)
- A unique certificate number (generated based on exam/course
  completion date and specific courses' titles)

**Regarding finding a way to make users input their birth year:**

I'm using **LearnDash** as my LMS and the only data that a user can input when creating their account for purchase is their full name, username, email, and password. I need a new field to be there so they can input their birth year (not natively possible in LearnDash).

**Regarding certificate number:**

The only solution I'm aware of is using an **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin in order to create new fields, and then using **Code Snippets** Plugin to gather the data from the users' exam completion date. From there, I'll need to somehow create a custom field for the certificate builder (there is no field for this in LearnDash).

How would I be able to do all these things? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: On a side note, using the last four digits of an SSN for anything is an extremely risky proposition - for many companies and services, that's all they ask for to verify your identity. The risk of identity theft that comes along with storing even just the last four digits of an SSN is so significant that I personally would not consider doing so unless absolutely business critical, and then not without a dedicated security team overseeing the storage and software maintenance. This is one of the reasons companies and institutions assign subjects an esoteric ID instead of organizing people by SSNs

Comment: If you're using it for some sort of identity verification, perform the verification immediately and discard it. Ideally the SSN should never move from system memory to any form of persistent storage.

Comment: The field can be replaced by the customer inputting their birth year instead. This way, their identification can be confirmed without any risk involved. Original post is updated to reflect this.